# Cannot fix unboundlocalError in my Django view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

So I have a view that is giving me "UnboundLocalError at /local variable 'word1' referenced before assignment". I have searched for other similar questions and I have tried to change the indentation but the problem won't fix. Can anyone tell me what's the problem? Help is much appreciated.

My views.py:

```
def index(request):
    form = WordForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        word1 = form.cleaned_data['Word1']
        word2 = form.cleaned_data['Word2']
        word3 = form.cleaned_data['Word3']
        result = form.cleaned_data['Result']

    context = {'form': form, 'word1': word1, 'word2': word2, 'word3': word3, 'result': result}
    return render(request, 'form.html', context)
```

Comment: You are only creating variables `word1`, `word2`, etc. when the form is *valid*, but you *use* these variables in the `context`, even if these ar enot valid hence the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only creating variables `word1`, `word2`, etc. when the form is *valid*, but you *use* these variables in the `context`, even if these ar enot valid hence the error.

You thus should assign something to `word1`, `word2`, `word3` and `result` in case the form is not valid, for example:

```
def index(request):
    form = WordForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        word1 = form.cleaned_data['Word1']
        word2 = form.cleaned_data['Word2']
        word3 = form.cleaned_data['Word3']
        result = form.cleaned_data['Result']
    else:
        word1 = word2 = word3 = result = None

    context = {'form': form, 'word1': word1, 'word2': word2, 'word3': word3, 'result': result}
    return render(request, 'form.html', context)
```